# Differential of Left and Right Translation Map, and Adjoint Map on $GL(n,\mathbb{R})$

Tags: differential-geometry

$L_A, R_A, C_A: GL(n,\mathbb{R}) \rightarrow GL(n,\mathbb{R})$ is defined as $L_A(X) = AX$, $R_A(X) = XA$, and $C_A(X)=AXA^{-1}$. I have to describe the differential of this map.

I know I have to start with a curve $\gamma$, with $\gamma(0)=X$, I tried considering the curve $\gamma(t) = \exp(tX)$, but for $0$ it isn't $X$, for $X \neq I$. I know that $DL_A$ is the same as $L_A$, except that it's domain and codomain are $\text{Mat}(n,\mathbb{R})$. Similarly for $R_A$. And once I know $DL_A$ and $DR_A$, I can just use the chain rule on $C_A = R_{A^{-1}} \circ L_A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to compute $(DL_A)_B(X)$, you want to consider the action on a curve $\gamma(t)$ through $B$ with tangent vector $X$. Modifying your idea slightly, take the curve to be $\gamma(t)=B\exp(tB^{-1}X)$. That is, you want
$$\frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} L_A(\gamma(t)) = \frac d{dt}\Big|_{t=0} AB\exp(tB^{-1}X)=AX.$$

Comment: I'm also trying to compute $DC_A(X)$, where $C_A(X)$ is defined above in the question. If I use the curve that you just provided with, I get $DC_A(X) = AXA^{-1}$. But we see that $C_A = R_{A^{-1}} \circ L_A=L_A \circ R_{A^{-1}}$. Applying chain rule gives me $DC_A(X)=AX^2$, and $DC_A(X)=AXA^{-1}XA^{-1}$ respectively. Clearly I'm going wrong somewhere. Can you point where?

Comment: Neither of these is correct. Think of it this way. All three of these maps are *linear* maps on the vector space of $n\times n$ matrices, and so they equal their own derivatives. This is equally true, then, when you restrict to the open subset $GL(n,\Bbb R)$. So $DC_A(X) = C_A(X) = AXA^{-1}$. Try doing the composition of two linear maps with the chain rule and figure out your error :)